# Specify int size in macro (or something)

Tags: c, types, 64-bit, bit, bit-shift

I'm trying to store 3 integers (ie 21 bits each) in one `long int` with these macros:

```
typedef long int Triple;
#define TR_A(o) ((int)((o & 0x7FFFFC0000000000) >> 42))
#define TR_B(o) ((int)((o & 0x000003FFFFE00000) >> 21))
#define TR_C(o) ((int)(o & 0x00000000001FFFFF))
#define MK_TR(a,b,c) ((long int)((a<<42) & (b<<21) & c))
```

So the idea is that `o` is 64 bits, and `a`,`b`,`c` are 32 each. When stored inside `o` they are 21 bits, and the 64 bits are empty bit, `a`, `b`, and then `c`.

I get a bunch of these errors:

```
warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
 #define MK_TR(a,b,c) ((long int)((a<<42) & (b<<21) & c))
                                    ^
```

Is it possible to add something to `TR_A`/`TR_B`/`TR_C` that specifies that `o` is long?

Any better way to do this?

I want to be able to return these as simple values, not pointers. Using Linux on PC.

Comment: Use a function that has types then use `uint_32t`, `int64_t`, etc.  and such types so that they are machine independent for size? https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer

Comment: @MichaelDorgan yes, I suppose that is what I need to do. I just have the feeling it ought to be possible with macros also.

Comment: I'm sure it is if you type cast each element coming in to the type you want, but sooo fragile.  `((long int)(a))<<42`...  Type thing would probably work.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan thanks, it worked on that error. I was trying to cast the parameters.

Comment: You say `a` is 32 bits, so `a<<42` is undefined behaviour. As commented, you need to make the cast *before* the shift.

Comment: If you just sweep this under the rug, you are going to pay the piper bigger in the future :)  Trust your compiler, use the correct types created from 20 years ago, and it's ok to use functions now.  I work on old OS level C code too, so I understand, but technical debt accrues interest...

Comment: Are you sure you want to bitwise AND in `MK_TR`?  Aren't you shifting your inputs enough that the non-zero bits don't overlap, so the result will be always zero?

Comment: you need to mask the upper bits of b and c

Comment: @PeterCordes well spotted. it should be OR, I guess.

Comment: @stark not sure what you mean - they are 32 bits cast to 64 (and the actual values will never be anywhere near that, maybe 15 bits or so)

Comment: Yes, if you want to pack 3 integers into bitfields of an `unsigned long long`, OR `|` is the normal way.  `+` works, too, if you've already masked them or otherwise know they're non-overlapping.  And BTW, in your source no, they haven't been cast to 64-bit.  That only happens *after* you shift out most of the bits out of the 32-bit `int` or whatever types `a,b,c` had originally, and AND (or OR) them together.  (As Michael commented, and Adrian's answer explained.)

Comment: I guess plus is better, it is more obvious that way

Comment: @PeterCordes I made the modification suggested by Michael above

Comment: No really; `|` is more idiomatic for combining bits.  `+` would make a reader wonder if any carry-propagation has to happen from two non-zero bits lining up with each other.

Comment: If they can't be negative, then why ints and not unsigned?

Comment: @stark they are unsigned now, but I may need negative values. have to have another round of thinking at some point

Comment: That's why I said you have to mask the upper bits.

Comment: @stark but what I really need (I guess) is to fit the 32 bits signed (but really only half of that max) into 21, before the casting and the shifting?

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support  two's complement signed ints in the range +/- 1M, both masking and shifting are required:

```
inline uint64_t make64(int a, int b, int c) {
    return ((uint64_t) (a & 0x1fffff) << 42) |
           ((uint64_t) (b & 0x1fffff) << 21) |
           ((uint64_t) c & 0x1fffff)
```

When splitting, the 12 sign bits will need to be restored:

```
inline int32_t get_a(uint64_t t) {
    return (int32_t)((t >> 42 & 0xfffff) | (t & 0x4000000000000000) ? 0xfff00000 : 0);
etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify that an integer literal (constant) should be interpreted as a `long int` by adding the `L` suffix (or a lowercase `l` - but this looks too much like a `1` for my comfort). Similarly, for a `long long int`, add the `LL` suffix.

In the case of your macros, you will also need to explicitly cast the arguments, `a`, `b` and `c` to the appropriate (`long` or `long long`) type.

However, rather than relying on a particular compiler to implement `long int` as a 64-bit type (many compilers do not, and use 32-bits for both `int` and `long int`, and require `long long int` for a 64-bit type), you should use the bit-width *specific* types defined in the `<stdint.h>` header file.

Thus, the following code should be warning-free *and portable*:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

typedef int64_t Triple;
#define TR_A(o) ((int32_t)(((int64_t)(o) & 0x7FFFFC0000000000LL) >> 42))
#define TR_B(o) ((int32_t)(((int64_t)(o) & 0x000003FFFFE00000LL) >> 21))
#define TR_C(o) ((int32_t)((int64_t)(o) & 0x00000000001FFFFFLL))
// EDIT/NOTE: I have changed the bitwise & operations to | in the macro below,
// as this is probably what you actually want (otherwise it will give 0 always)!
#define MK_TR(a,b,c) ((int64_t)(((int64_t)(a) << 42) | ((int64_t)(b) << 21) | (int64_t)(c)))
```

Also, it is very good practice to always include your macro arguments in parentheses (such as `(c)` in the last line, above). Without this, a call to your macro with an *expression* as an argument can give you unexpected results, which can be difficult to track down. This would be a case in point:

```cpp
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
Triple test = MK_TR(a + 1, b + 1, c + 1); // Unexpected(?) result.
```

Comment: Or just use functions where the type isn't made up as you go...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Indeed. I understand there is a lot of 'anti-macro' feeling in the C/C++ community, but the OP did ask a question about macros. Personally, I would also prefer functions for this case.

Comment: There is (or can be) a place for macros still, don't get me wrong.  But for simple things like this, especially when types are causing bad things, a function is better.  @Fredrik, by made up, I should say not specified - the power of macros :)

Comment: Generally prefer `unsigned long long` for the bits being right-shifted.  Also, there's no benefit to promoting the shift-count to `int64_t`.  The C shift operator (unlike others) does *not* require both operands to have the same type.  It would be perfectly fine to just use `>> 42` in TR_A.

Comment: @PeterCordes On your second (very good) point, see latest edit (makes the code a lot simpler, also). On your first point: in the stuff to be right-shifted, the MSB (sign bit) is always cleared by the masks, so there shouldn't be a problem using signed ints.

Comment: Right, it should work fine with signed `int64_t`.  Especially since int64_t is required to be a 2's complement type if it exists at all, and `long long` is required to be wide enough to represent `0x7FFFFC0000000000LL` as a signed positive integer. (In case anyone still cares about theoretical portability to non-2's-complement).  Unsigned for bitfields is idiomatic, though.  Using signed ints makes me wonder why arithmetic right shifts are needed, and if any sign-extension is happening.